# Can't login to CentOS desktop as root via GUI prompt

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, root

I have CentOS 6.5 running on a VM in VirtualBox (Windows host). I had no problems logging in as root from the GUI prompt (clicking on Other and typing root, then my root password and getting the desktop as the root user) last Friday, but this morning, when I log in as root, I just get a blank desktop and a blank taskbar (no menu bar, icons, etc).

I can switch to root from my other user account in Terminal using `su root` but that's pretty much it.

Any suggestions? I am not very familiar with Linux in general, so please bear with me.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes, multiple times.